# How to deal with a Dirac delta function numerically?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

I need to solve some differential equations with a Dirac delta function. e.g. the source terms are like, $\delta(x)$ and $\partial_x \delta(x)$.

Could I just use the Gaussian type function? e.g.

$$ \delta(x-a) = a_1\exp(-\frac{(x-a)^2}{2a_2}),$$ and,
$$ \partial_x \delta(x-a) = - \frac{a_1}{a_2}(x+a_1)\exp(-\frac{(x-a)^2}{2a_2})  $$

where by setting e.g. $a_1=1000$, $a_2=0.01$.

If the answer is yes, then how to choose the reasonable values of $a_1$ and $a_2$?

Thanks!

Comment: The $a_1$ and $a_2$ are not independent, they are bound by the condition that the integral over whole space is $1$. You can see the exact expressions for various "finite" delta functions on the Wikipedia page

Comment: If you are using finite differences on an equidistant grid with step $h$, then your delta function becomes a scaled Kroneker symbol $$\delta(x-x') \to \frac{1}{h} \delta_{n, n'}$$

Comment: Maybe you can integrate the differential equation to get a right hand side that contains an ordinary function instead of the Dirac measure?